# Change PolicyBanner 'accept' button text

Tags: macos

Our company's computer needs a policy notice prior to login. Now it's says 'Accept'. Is there a way to change the 'Accept' button? Do I have to search in the OS UI or is it simply a text object?

In case it motivates. I want to change the policy "accept" button it to "whatever".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Become a root user: `sudo su`
2. change directory to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/MachServices/SecurityAgent.bundle/Contents/Resources/Base.lproj`
3. There is the file called `PolicyBanner.nib`. This is a binary file, so
   change it to text file to edit it: `plutil -convert xml1 PolicyBanner.nib`
4. Open the file with your favorite editor, and search for the strings like this:
   `"<string>100068.title</string>"
                   "<string>Accept</string>"`
5. Change "Accept" to any strings you want.
6. Save the file and done

Comment: Cool, I will check a.s.a.p.!

Answer (score 3):

Please see the above answer, it holds updated information.

<s>I have scoured all Apple manuals, support forums and taken a quick search of the system files and I have discovered the 'Accept' button text is hard-coded to some extent, meaning it's not possible to change it right now, unless someone creates a patch or workaround. The reason for this is probably that the banner is meant to be **an agreement** and not a 'Welcome Message' as such. You can see in the picture on [this article](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT4788) on Apple Support, the titlebar clearly displays 'Agreement'. I hope this answers your question.</s>